# Is it possible to use "PowerMockito.whenNew()" only for first occurence?

Tags: java, constructor, powermock, powermockito

I'm about to build up a JSON object and want to test the result.
I'm calling a public method. There several private methods and a recursive call is made. Somewhere at the beginning I have this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
```

This is my "root" object. Unfortunately it is not given as a parameter or such, but created with constructor as shown.
Within the recursvie call this constructor gets being called several more times to build the structure. What I need is the root object for assertion in test.

So I tried to get it somehow and tried this approach here ... following code:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
PowerMockito.whenNew(JSONObject.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(json);

[...]

assertThat(json.get("bla"), is("hello")); // assertions possible to my root json object
```

This would me allow to have the built up root json object after execution for my assertions.
BUT I run into a stackoverflow Exception. Why? Because the recursivly called constructors get now passed my root object insead calling the constructor.

So bottomline, what I need here: I want to say "whenNew(JSONObject.class, times(1))" or something similar. So that only the first constructor call gets mocked, and the following not anymore.
I thought this should be possible, but can't find a way to achieve this :(

Thanks for any help, guys!

Comment: Your test is doing its job and telling you your design is inadequate. Why isn't this object returned by the method or otherwise passed along to another collaborator? Why are you trying to assert in this fashion?

Comment: Yeah I know the code is to blame, but I'm not really in a good position to change anything as it is legacy code, widely used across several places etc etc. Even if not, it made me now quiet curious whether this goal is possible using Powermockito. Just ignore the context if it helps :p

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I had a main JSONObject and some of inner JSONObjects, but I only wanted the first one, and the others could work as usual. Basically, you have to set the instances after the first time too.

```
final JSONObject requestJSON = new JSONObject();
final JSONObject innerJSONExample = new JSONObject();
final JSONObject anotherInnerJSONExample = new JSONObject();

PowerMockito.whenNew(JSONObject.class).withNoArguments()
   .thenReturn(requestJSON)      //first return
   .thenReturn(innerJSONExample) //second return
   .thenReturn(anotherInnerJSONExample); //third return and so on...
//I will not use innerJSONExample and the other, but this is needed
```

It's important to mention that you must create the instances ***BEFORE*** the *whenNew*. Also, you ***CANNOT*** do this:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(JSONObject.class).withNoArguments()
   .thenReturn(requestJSON)      //first return
   .thenReturn(new JSONObject()); //second return
```

Because you've already set that when *"new JSONObject()"* return *"requestJSON"*, then, when you do this, you're returning the same *"requestJSON"*, and you might get *StackOverflowError*.